# Are swift actions allowed during surprise round

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, actions

I know that normally you are only allowed either a standard or move action during a surprise round. Also you are allowed a free action. The book says nothing about swift actions during the surprise round. Is it assumed that since they are not mentioned they are not allowed?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## A Swift Action Can Be Taken During the Surprise Round

The [Surprise Round](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Surprise) says...

> If some but not all of the combatants are aware of their opponents, a surprise round happens before regular rounds begin. In initiative order (highest to lowest), combatants who started the battle aware of their opponents each take a standard or move action during the surprise round. ***You can also take free actions during the surprise round.*** If no one or everyone is surprised, no surprise round occurs.

Emphasis mine. Then there's this about [Swift Actions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Swift-Actions)...

> A swift action consumes a very small amount of time, but represents a larger expenditure of effort than a free action. You can perform one swift action per turn without affecting your ability to perform other actions. In that regard, a swift action is like a free action. You can, however, perform only one single swift action per turn, regardless of what other actions you take. ***You can take a swift action anytime you would normally be allowed to take a free action.*** Swift actions usually involve spellcasting, activating a feat, or the activation of magic items.

Emphasis mine. So, yeah, swift actions are allowed in the surprise round.

Unlike other games in which characters can take *more* significant actions to perform *less* significant actions, *Pathfinder* and its antecedents have firm limits on the actions that can be taken during a round, including the surprise round. [Actions in Combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Actions-In-Combat) says

> In a normal round, you can perform a standard action and a move action, or you can perform a full-round action. You can also perform one swift action and one or more free actions. You can always take a move action in place of a standard action.
>
> In some situations (such as in a surprise round), you may be limited to taking only a single move action or standard action.

Other than taking a move action instead of a standard action, there's no way under normal circumstances to take an action of one type in place of an action of another type.

**Examples**

- During his turn in the surprise round, a character ***can't*** take two swift actions, replacing the move action or standard action he's normally allowed with a *second* swift action.
- During his turn in a normal round, a character ***can't*** take three swift actions, replacing the move action *and* move action or standard action he's normally allowed with a *second and third* swift action.